# Error in update SQL statement (Multi column and multi table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, multiple-columns

I can not find the error of this SQL statement:

```
update temptable2
set dep5 = stt.departureTime,
    arv4 = stt.departureTime,
    dur4 = arv4-dep4,
    arv5 = dur5+dep5
from temptable2 as tt
join stoptimetable as stt on stt._tripID = tt.dur4 
                          and stt._stopID = tt.id5 
                          and stt.stopSequence = tt.dep5
```

Error:

> SQL Error: near "from": syntax error

I read this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#BasicSyntax) completely but I couldn't find the error

Comment: Please provide information about the error code/message in detail.

Comment: SQL Error: near "from": syntax error

Comment: Where do these `arv4`, `dep4`, `dur5`, `dep5` columns come from that you use in the third and fourth `SET` line?? You might need to prefix those with a table alias, too

Comment: I think you should use `UPDATE tt` instead of `UPDATE temptable2`

Comment: Please show table schemas

Comment: How can see the table schema and after that put here?

Comment: @Malus `sp_help temptable2` (and `sp_help stoptimetable`), then copy output, then click "edit" link just above these comments, then paste into question, then click "Save edits"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stoptimetable](
    [_tripID] [int] NULL,
    [_stopID] [int] NULL,
    [stopSequence] [int] NULL,
    [departureTime] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temptable2](
    [dep5] [int] NULL,
    [arv4] [int] NULL,
    [dur4] [int] NULL,
    [arv5] [int] NULL,
    [id5] [int] NULL,
    [dep4] [int] NULL,
    [dur5] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

update temptable2
set dep5 = stt.departureTime,
    arv4 = stt.departureTime,
    dur4 = arv4-dep4,
    arv5 = dur5+dep5
from temptable2 as tt
join stoptimetable as stt on stt._tripID = tt.dur4 
                          and stt._stopID = tt.id5 
                          and stt.stopSequence = tt.dep5
```

> (0 row(s) affected)

This compiles and runs. I need your schema to perform further error search.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to update `temptable2`, but that table is not one of the tables you have referenced; there is only `tt` and `stt`.

Change your query to `update tt ...`

When you alias a table, that's the name of the table for the query. The real name of the table is not assessable.

Comment: That's not true. As you can see in my code sample, his query compiles and executes without error, if the schema is correct.